# Get a percentage of all in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table containing a list of features that will be implemented by a given team for a given release, with a flag to tell me if the feature is testable or not.

Sample data can be:

```
feature   team         rel       testable
1           1           1            1
2           1           1            1
3           1           1            1
4           1           2            1
5           1           2            1
6           1           2            0
7           1           3            0
8           1           3            0
9           1           3            1
10          2           1            0
11          2           1            0
12          2           1            0
13          2           2            1
14          2           2            0
15          2           2            0
16          2           3            1
17          2           3            1
18          2           3            0
```

What I try to get is, for each team and each release, what is the percentage of testable feature (over the overall count of features ***for this team and release***.

Ideally I would like to keep it as a single SQL query due to the way I designed the display of the result.

I went as far as this:

```
SELECT 
    MyTable.team AS team, 
    MyTable.rel AS rel,
    (COUNT(*)*100 / (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM MyTable 
        WHERE 
            [MyTable].team = team 
            AND [MyTable].rel = rel
        )
    ) AS result
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    MyTable.team IN (1,2) 
    AND MyTable.rel IN (1,2,3) 
    AND MyTable.testable = 1 
GROUP BY 
    MyTable.rel, 
    MyTable.team 
ORDER BY 
    MyTable.team, 
    MyTable.rel
```

Here is the result I expect (I don't really care about the rounding)

```
team    rel   result
1        1      1      // all are testable for team 1 release 1
1        2     0.66    // 2 out of 3 are testable for team 1 release 2
1        3     0.33
2        1      0
2        2     0.33
2        3     0.66
```

My feeling is that I am not that far from the solution, but I am not able to fix it.

Comment: use the average 'avg' function.  what data type is testable?

Comment: It is Access "yes/no"... but i can actually change it to number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think a simple average function would work here; assuming all values in the testable field are 1 or 0 only.

oh and get rid of testable = 1 in where clause

I'm not sure if access will implicitly cast the Boolean... so this will enable the avg to work by converting the value to 1,0 explicitly.

```
SELECT 
    MyTable.team AS team, 
    MyTable.rel AS rel,
    AVG(iif(Testable,1,0)) AS result
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    MyTable.team IN (1,2) 
    AND MyTable.rel IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY 
    MyTable.rel, 
    MyTable.team 
ORDER BY 
    MyTable.team, 
    MyTable.rel
```

Comment: Wait... this is Access, not SQL Server. In any case, if it's a Boolean column, you still need to do the translation to 1 and 0, so good job.

Comment: That is simple and brilliant at the same time. I didn't think at all about this way, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
select y.team, y.rel, x.cnt/y.tot as res
from (
select t.team, t.rel, sum(x.cnt) as tot
from (
select team, rel, testable, count(*) as cnt
from table where team in (1,2) and rel in (1,2,3)
group by team, rel, testable) x
join table t on t.team = x.team and t.rel = x.rel
group by team, rel) y
```

You can try this.